# 2-pass rate control in HEVC encoder or x265

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-encoding, hevc, libx265

I want to use 2-pass rate control in the HEVC encoder reference code but I do not know if there is a configuration setting to do it. My goal is to encode an original sequence in the 1st-pass rate control and encode a filtered sequence of the original sequence in the 2nd-pass.

I see this can be done in [FFmpeg](https://superuser.com/questions/1055190/2-pass-ratecontrol-in-ffmpeg) and [x265](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.265), but giving two different input videos (original and filtered) to the encoder, does it still even make sense? Any ideas on how to do it in the HEVC encoder/x265 or any comments would be appreciated.

Comment: *"giving two different input videos [for each pass] does it still even make sense?"* No. Each pass must have the same input. What is the ultimate goal here?

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Ilogan. But why no, though? I mean, even with the input for the 1-pass is the original, and for the 2-pass, is the pre-filtered of the original? In this case, the pre-filtered is aimed at using the same frame-level QP set as the original video during the encoding loop with rate control enabled, which I think can be done with 2-pass.

Comment: Pre-filtered? Not sure what you mean. I guess I don't understand what you want to do and what the actual desired result is. I was assuming for pass 1 you give it the original. Pass 2 is the original that was modified with various filters and possibly a different output format.